# Get weekday by number

Tags: php, date, strtotime

We all know date('w').

What I am trying to do is to find the next Date with the index retrieved from another date('w').

I tried:

```
$saturday = 6;
if((int)date('w') < $saturday){
    $targetdate = strtotime('last Sunday +'.$saturday.' days');
}else{
    $targetdate = strtotime('next Sunday +'.$saturday.' days');
}
```

But it ist not as reliable as I hoped when today is sunday.

Any best practice on this?

Answer (score 1):

I could not find a quick way to do that. But I found a passable way around it (in case it helps someone):

```
$days = array(
        0 => 'Sunday',
        1 => 'Monday',
        2 => 'Tuesday',
        3 => 'Wednesday',
        4 => 'Thursday',
        5 => 'Friday',
        6 => 'Saturday'
    );
$targetdate = strtotime('next '.$saturday]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please just do:

```
date("l", strtotime("monday +$weekday_index days" ) )
```

Smoother than having to define an array each time!